# How to let CKEditor allow data-label tags?

Tags: javascript, html

I want my CKEditor to allow data-label tags, but for some reason the code that is supposed to allow it doesn't work.

Here is my current code:

```
<form method="post">
<label for="pname">Page name:</label><br />
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $fetchp['pname']; ?>" name="pname" autocomplete="off" /><hr />
<label for="pcontent">Page content:</label><br />
<textarea name="pcontent" id="pcontent" rows="10" cols="80"><?php echo $fetchp['pcontent']; ?></textarea><br />
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace('pcontent', {enterMode : CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR, extraAllowedContent: 'section article header nav aside[lang,foo] data-label'});
</script>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Don't worry about that $fetch thing, that all works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to put:

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```

In the config.js